# Using the "Select Top (100) percent vs. Select * , or selecting any column"

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, select

I wrote the first query below that I was hopeing to give me the exact same results that the 2nd query does, but it seems there is one recrod different:

```
    SELECT     DocumentSourceName
     FROM         dbo.DocumentSource
     WHERE     (DocumentSourceName NOT IN
                      (SELECT     DocumentSourceName
                        FROM          dbo.DocumentSource AS DocumentSource_1
                        WHERE      (DocumentSourceName LIKE 'ZZ%')))
```

Versus

```
    SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT f.FacilityName, ds.DocumentSourceName, ds.DocumentSourceNotes
    FROM         dbo.DocumentSource AS ds INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Facility AS f ON ds.DocumentSourceFacility = f.FacilityID
    WHERE     (ds.DocumentSourceName NOT LIKE 'ZZ%') AND (ds.DocumentSourceInactive = 0)
```

So is it because of the "Top 100 percent" that I think its the same as the '*' or its because I have the "AND" in the "Where" Clause? Please advice. Thanks

Comment: Since your WHERE clauses are different, that is the most likely cause of different results. "TOP 100 PERCENT" has no effect; the results would be the same if it were excluded.

Comment: @dartonw Thanks you for the clarifying this, as it puzzled me when I saw Top and the 100, then its the same as SELECT *.
I will check the filtering in the Where clause, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TOP does nothing - based on the fact that it's "100%".

The first query is essentially the same as:
`WHERE (ds.DocumentSourceName NOT LIKE 'ZZ%')`, but the second has more filters...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will have to know the data better to judge why they added this filter that I wasn't thinking of.